# Apache Spark and MongoDb Date issue

Tags: java, mongodb, date, apache-spark

I am trying to extract data from mongo based on date range using apache spark.

My ObjectId is

```
 ObjectId("56a3c6a80000000000000000")
```

On query to mongo using this objectId

```
 db.myCollection.find({"_id":{"$gt":ObjectId("56a3c6a80000000000000000")}}).sort({_id:-1}).count();
```

I am getting result

```
2685088
```

I converted it into time using

```
 ObjectId("56a3c6a80000000000000000").getTimestamp().getTime()
```

got the result

```
 1453573800000
```

Now my apache spark query is

```
config.set("mongo.input.query","{\"_id\": {\"$gt\": {\"$date\": 1453573800000}}}");
```

When I am executing this using spark java code, on console, I can see the

```
query={ "_id" : { "$gt" : { "$date" : "2016-01-23T18:30:00.000Z"}}}
```

but spark is not giving any result also it is executing  whole mongo.

More precisely, I want something like this mongo statement to be executed in spark

```
db.collection.find({_id:{$gt: ObjectId(Math.floor((new Date('2016/1/22'))/1000).toString(16) + "0000000000000000"), 
$lt: ObjectId(Math.floor((new Date('2016/1/23'))/1000).toString(16) +   "0000000000000000")}})
```

I found similar class https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/blob/3dafe6e2415edd3e9760e51facd7f883d4e0a364/examples/treasury_yield/src/test/java/com/mongodb/hadoop/TestStreaming.java

I am not sure if it works too.

Comment: What do you mean by "also it is executing all whole mongo"?

Comment: It is searching for whole mongodb instead of date greater "2016-01-23"